# Why Mac chrome print image with white background color

Tags: html, css, background-color, color-codes

## Expected behavior

- Image tag print image with non-background.

## Actual behavior

- Print image with white background.

### Html

```
<img src="png/ic-trigger.png" srcset="png/ic-trigger@2x.png 2x, png/ic-trigger@3x.png 3x" class="ic-emergency-on">
```

### Css

- Printed with white background.

`

```
.ic-emergency-on {
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    left: 8px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 18px;
    background-color: #fafafa;
}
```

`

- None-background

`

```
.ic-emergency-on {
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    left: 8px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 18px;
    background-color: #00fafafa;
}
```

`

So, what I want is there is another solution that not print white background color?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the hex value for `background-color: #00FAFAFA;` is acting weird or isn't a real hex value you can use.

I would just use `background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);` for transparency.

Comment: 00FAFAFA is not a valid code. A hex triplet is a six-digit, three-byte hexadecimal number used in HTML, CSS, SVG, and other computing applications to represent colors.

Comment: [8 digit hex codes are valid in CSS Colors Level 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/#hex-notation)

Answer (score 1):

`#00FAFAFA` is not a valid code. A hex triplet is a six-digit, three-byte hexadecimal number used in HTML, CSS, SVG, and other computing applications to represent colors. Kindly recheck your color code.

Comment: [8 digit hex codes are valid in CSS Colors Level 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/#hex-notation)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use the 8 digit hex colour (#RRGGBBAA) syntax from [CSS Colors Level 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/#hex-notation), which is [not currently supported in Chrome](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-rrggbbaa).

Use decimal notation instead:

```
background-color: rgba(0, 250, 250, 0.98);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found simple solution.

Just delete background-color tag